# React Apollo to graphql-php server on different ports

Tags: reactjs, cors, react-apollo, graphql-php

I'm trying to connect my create-react-app frontend to my graphql-php server using Apollo. As both are running on different ports on my local machine (3000 and 8080 respectively) I'm getting some CORS issues.
Apollo is sending an OPTIONS request which is then throwing a console log message of:

```
 DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Error: Network request failed with status 200 - "OK" could not be cloned.
        at ApolloClient.hookLogger [as devToolsHookCb] (<anonymous>:14:14)
        at QueryManager.onBroadcast (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2585:27)
        at QueryManager../node_modules/apollo-client/core/QueryManager.js.QueryManager.broadcastQueries (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3659:14)
        at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3230:31
        at <anonymous>
```

Would love any help that anyone can provide as to how to get these two to talk to each other!

Frontend Apollo config:

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({uri:'http://localhost:8080/temps_api/index.php'}); //TODO: Separate into config file
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor\autoload.php';
require_once 'core\bootstrap.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

use GraphQL\GraphQL;
use GraphQL\Type\Schema;
use Temps\Types\Types;

$schema = new Schema([
    'query' => Types::query()
]);

// $data = Data::parseInput();

var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));

//Test query
// $data = [
//   'query' => '
//     {
//         user(email: "jane@email.com", password: "password") {
//             __typename,
//             username,
//             userType,
//             email
//         }
//     }'
// ];
//This method will vlidate the POST variables and turn them into $data array

$result = GraphQL::executeQuery(
    $schema,
    $data['query']
);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a few headers right before you echo out the results. Like this

```
header('Content-Type: application/json', true, $httpStatus);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');
    }
}

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```